# Report analysis

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Please can you provide me the detailed analysis of the attached graph,Just a general review.This is a composite graph related to transaction,response and active threads.
I am not able to explain this graph to my client.
Configuration-
Thread-500
Ramp up-100
loop count-1.
Is it good to go or not,or what about the spikes,errors that needs to be handle.What are the reason for this error and what can we do to fix it.Please let me know.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvOZ0.png)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKfsi.png

Answer (score 0):

At peak transactions(red-line) we would have expected peak errors(pink-line) and peak response time(blue-line). Oddly however, the peak errors occurred on the down ramp of transactions, implying a lag in processing while response times abnormally continued to increase. Based on my experience this implies strained system resources, try increasing the server's system resources and retest for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

2 screenshots is not enough to perform analysis, however looking into them I can figure out the following:

1. On well-behaved system throughput should increase as the load increases. On this one it doesn't.
2. Response time continues to grow even when load ended. It normally indicates memory leak on application under test side. Try going for [Soak Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing) - put the application under prolonged load and see if it fail with the form of out of memory error.
3. I would also recommend [monitoring system resources on application under test side](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) as application can misbehave if it lacks i.e. RAM or due to slow disk. It might be cheaper to add RAM or replace disk than to tune the application to fit into existing hardware.